Do staging ground questions that never graduate to the main site count against the user for the purpose of the question quality filters?
There are some questions that surged about how staging grounds actually works (as in, how the system behaves in different circumstances). It is clear that if you are question banned, you can't use the questions/ask route, since that is checked first, to not waste your time in writing into the ask box, but would questions that never graduated to main site count against you? The question quality filter considers zero scored questions, which every question on the staging ground is, so it is reasonable to say that it also counts for the quality filters. Is this assumption correct?

I think it would also be interesting to know how it handles published Staging Ground questions as the Staging Ground posts still exists in a "Posted" state as a distinct entry.

"The question quality filter considers zero scored questions" - Are you sure zero-score questions negatively impact users with respect to question bans if the question isn't closed or deleted by the author and and there are no answers to that question? At least I don't see that listed in What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?.

I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "surged".  Can you reword?

@D.W. you don't need to understand that word to understand the post, just keep reading. I assumed myself that it meant that there are numerous of them. "A surge".

@dan1st "So, if many of your questions aren't answered, or are downvoted, closed, or deleted" Zero scored non-answered counts against you.

TylerH is correct, but adding as an official response as well.
Questions in Staging ground are not included for the purposes of question ask quality checks.  If a question goes on to graduate, its corresponding post on the main site will be used, but independent of any association to SG.
As you noted, this would also be quite unfair to penalize SG questions for having a "score" of 0, since there are no votes in SG.

Ok, then can we remove restrictions on users being able to post questions to the Staging Ground even if they are in the question filter checks? Or should this be a separated feature request?

@Braiam, it's probably best as a separate feature request.  We do have some ideas we've already worked on a bit around separate quality checks to enter staging ground vs main site.  The idea being to give as much grace to new SG users as possible in trying to successfully ask a question, balanced with not allowing people to spam the site repeatedly.

Does given answer imply that a new asker may remove their question from SG and ask a new question (which likely will go to the SG again), and given procedure could be repeated any number of times without consequences for the asker? Or are there some automatic barriers which prevent this behavior? (Not to mean that given behavior is always malicious, just wanted to know.)


would questions that never graduated to main site count against you

No, I don't think so. Only questions on the main site are counted toward question bans. Questions that never leave the Staging Ground are not on the main site.

I would also assume that - but I don't know about this being confirmed anywhere.

I'm not sure, as the quality filters need to be aware of staging ground questions. In case of someone that has tripped the ban, they get to ask a single question each 6 months. If that question goes to the staging ground, they shouldn't immediately be able to ask a second question and thus have two questions while they only should be able to ask one. It would be great to have official documentation on how this works.
